# Regular expression split string, extract string value before and numeric value between square brackets

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to parse a `string` that looks like "Abc[123]". The numerical value between the brackets is needed, as well as the `string` value before the brackets.

The most examples that I tested work fine, but have problems to parse some special cases.

This code seems to work fine for "normal" cases, but has some problems handling "special" cases:

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*[0-9])\]";
var query = "Abc[123]";
var numVal = Regex.Matches(query, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).FirstOrDefault();
var stringVal = Regex.Split(query, pattern)
                  .Select(x => x.Trim())
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

How should the code be adjusted to handle also some special cases?
For instance for the string "Abc[]" the parser should return correctly "Abc" as the string value and indicate an empty the numeric value (which could be eventually defaulted to 0).
For the string "Abc[xy33]" the parser should return "Abc" as the string value and indicate an invalid numeric value.
For the string "Abc" the parser should return "Abc" as the string value and indicate a missing numeric value. The blanks before/after or inside the brackets should be trimmed "Abc [ 123 ] ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^([^\[]+)\[([^\]]*)\]`

Explanation of a pattern:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`([^\[]+)` - match one or more of any character ecept `[` and store it insinde first capturing group

`\[` - match `[` literally

`([^\]]*)` - match zero or more of any character except `]` and store inside second capturing group

`\]` - match `]` literally

Here's tested code:

```
  var pattern = @"^([^\[]+)\[([^\]]*)\]";
  var queries = new string[]{ "Abc[123]", "Abc[xy33]", "Abc[]", "Abc[ 33 ]", "Abc" };
  foreach (var query in queries)
  {
    string beforeBrackets;
    string insideBrackets;
    var match = Regex.Match(query, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
      beforeBrackets = match.Groups[1].Value;
      insideBrackets = match.Groups[2].Value.Trim();
      if (insideBrackets == "")
        insideBrackets = "0";
      else if (!int.TryParse(insideBrackets, out int i))
        insideBrackets = "incorrect value!";
    }
    else
    {
      beforeBrackets = query;
      insideBrackets = "no value";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Input string {query} : before brackets: {beforeBrackets}, inside brackets: {insideBrackets}");
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the code seems to cover the requested use-cases !

Comment: Later edit: It does not cover the case when the string has no brackets at all, like "Abc".

Comment: @RickyTad Updated answer.

Comment: How should the pattern be changed, to be able to handle optional additional text between the brackets ? For instance, these should all be valid strings: ```Abc[12]``` , ```Abc[int:123]```, ```Abc[bool: 5]```, ```Abc[float : 32 ]```

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a regex replacement on the input, for a one-liner solution:

```
string input = "Abc[123]";
string letters = Regex.Replace(input, "\\[.*\\]", "");
string numbers = Regex.Replace("Abc[123]", ".*\\[(\\d+)\\]", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(letters);
Console.WriteLine(numbers);
```

This prints:

```
Abc
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there'd be some language-based techniques for that, which I wouldn't know, yet with a regular expression, we'd capture everything using capturing groups and check for things one by one, maybe:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)\s*(\[?)\s*([A-Za-z]*)(\d*)\s*(\]?)\s*$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ixVc4w/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ixVc4w/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that easily without using regex

```
string temp = "Abc[123]";
string[] arr =  temp.Split('[');
string name = arr[0];
string value = arr[1].ToString().TrimEnd(']');
```

output name = `Abc`, and value = `123`